# How to interpret ast.literal_eval() ValueError message?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, valueerror

When attempting to use `ast.literal_eval()` on an extremely massive string I receive the error `ValueError: malformed node or string on line 1: <ast.Name object at 0x000001FAAA9B1420>`. It is prohibitively time consuming to go through the entire string looking for where `ast.literal_eval()` found an item of a type it can't handle. The error message seems to give a location for where it errored as some sort of hex value, but how do I interpret `0x000001FAAA9B1420` to see where this is in the input string?

How would I see the index in the string at which `ast.literal_eval()` errored by referencing the `ValueError` error message? Is there any way to see this index otherwise?

Comment: Unfortunately, the hex value `0x000001FAAA9B1420` in the error message is not the location of the error in the input string. It is actually the memory address of the object that was created when attempting to parse the string using `ast.literal_eval()`.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval("x")` would reproduce this problem - you've got something that looks like a variable name (which `literal_eval()` explicitly does not support).  That hex number is the memory address of an object, it's of no use in finding out where the problem was.

Comment: *In this specific case*, you could use `ast.parse()` to compile the string, then `ast.walk()` to search for the offending `Name` object; it will have `lineno` and `col_offset` fields that tell where in the string it was located.  But that wouldn't work with all possible failures, such as outright syntax errors.

Comment: @jasonharper I couldn't find a suitable duplicate; your commentary seems good enough to me to form the basis of an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @jasonharper's comment, this is the solution that worked for me:

```
parsedString = ast.parse(reallyLongString)
for node in ast.walk(parsedString):
     if isinstance(node, ast.Name): #Detects variable names
          print(reallyLongString[node.col_offset - 5:node.col_offset + 5])
```

This prints the parts of the string that will error out `ast.literal_eval`. Turns out my problem was that an API response was giving me non-Python values instead of `None`, `True`, and `False`. So the end solution was:

```
reallyLongString = reallyLongString.replace('null', 'None')
reallyLongString = reallyLongString.replace('true', 'True')
reallyLongString = reallyLongString.replace('false', 'False')
reallyLongDict = ast.literal_eval(reallyLongString)
```

Comment: An API response containing `null`, `true`, and `false` sounds like JSON - the built-in `json` module would be the proper way to handle that, rather than munging the string into something that `ast.literal_eval()` can handle.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Also, feel free to write your own response and I will select it as the answer, as mine was from your comment.